# jsf, richfaces, popup window

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I would like to make a list-detail view with richfaces. There will be a link for every record in the list that should open a new window containing record details.
I tried to implement the link this way:

```
<a4j:commandLink oncomplete="window.open('/pages/serviceDetail.jsf','popupWindow', 'dependent=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no, height=500, width=400')" actionListener="#{monitoringBean.recordDetail}"  value="details" />
```

I use `<a4j:keepAlive beanName="monitoringBean" ajaxOnly="false" />` for both the list and the detail page. recordDetail method fills the data of the selected record to a variable of the bean that I would like to display on the detail page.

The problem is that keepalive doesn't work, so I get new bean instance on the detail page every time. So the the previously selected record from the other bean is not accessible here.
Is there a way to pass parameter (id) to the detail page to handle record selection. Or is there any way to make keepalive work? (I this this would be the easiest).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using `window.open(..)` - it will fail on most browser configurations nowadays (due to pop-up blocking).

Use [`<rich:modalPanel>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_modalPanel.html) instead.